# Why my bottom navigation bar doesn't appear

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I set my bottom navigation bar, but somehow I can't see it on my screen.

My setup proccess:

**xml**:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="24dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
 />
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
    />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

**menu**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:title="@string/home" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/newsList"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:title="@string/news_list" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:title="@string/settings" />
</menu>
```

**MainActivity**:

```
bottom_nav_view.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Where am I doing wrong? I checked some tutorials, and that exactly the process of setting bottom navigation view

Comment: For items set this attribute: app:showAsAction="always"

Comment: Still, does not appear..I can't see it even in the main activity.xml design tab

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this **height** and **weight** for your fragment tag:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
 />
```

Comment: Works, thank you. just general question - if the match parent height was the problem, why I could see the app bar and the fragment didn't overlap it too?

Comment: When you use `match_parent` as a layout dimension in `LinearLayout` the view expands as much as your containing parent (`LinearLayout`) which is not your intention in this case. You would rather prefer filling the left over space between your other views (toolbar and bottom nav) which you should use declare it this way. The reason the toolbar was visible was its order of declaration which was first and your fragment was pushed out of view `?attr/actionBarSize` pixels.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code according to my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="24dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav_view"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This code is tested my myself and working correctly

Thankew! Happy coding